# Sort an array that has normal string elements and "number-like" string elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, sorting

I have an array that includes float-like strings like `"4.5"`, and regular strings like `"Hello"`. I want to sort the array so that regular strings come at the end and the float-like strings come before them and are sorted by their float value.

I did:

```
@arr.sort {|a,b| a.to_f <=> b.to_f }
```

Comment: have a look at http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_f, a.to_f returns 0.0 if a is not valid number, you'll want to check for this using a supplied block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = ["21.4", "world", "6.2", "1.1", "hello"]

arr.sort_by { |s| Float(s) rescue Float::INFINITY }
  #=> ["1.1", "6.2", "21.4", "world", "hello"]
```

Comment: You could extend this to `[(Float(s) rescue Float::INFINITY), s]` if you want the strings at the end sorted too.

Answer (score 1):

sort in ruby 1.9+

```
["1.2", "World", "6.7", "3.4", "Hello"].sort
```

will return

```
["1.2", "3.4", "6.7", "Hello", "World"]
```

You can use @cary solution for certain edge cases eg ["10.0","3.2","hey","world"]

Comment: What about `['10.0', '9.0', 'cat']`?

Comment: Yes it wont work but i used the value "4.5" given by op and based my answer on it.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty:

```
arry = ["1", "world", "6", "21", "hello"]
# separate "number" strings from other strings
tmp = arry.partition { |x| Float(x) rescue nil }
# sort the "numbers" by their numberic value
tmp.first.sort_by!(&:to_f)
# join them all in a single array
tmp.flatten!
```

Will probably suit your needs